There is interference when selecting faces. What to do?

I select the faces of the image using shift.The picture shows interference in orange. This interference is also visible when simply pressing on the face, not just when selecting. When I hold down the mouse wheel, everything returns to normal, but as soon as I release it, the interference appears again.
I tried to reinstall, nothing worked

Clean up your geometry. I don't know what you did to mess it up, but it looks as if there were duplicated faces. Select one which shows "interference" and delete it. There most likely is another one in that place. And what do you mean by "pressing on the face"?

I mean just a simple mouse click without selection. Sorry, English is not my native language, so there may be such inaccuracies

But a simple mouse click on a face selects it, so it is a selection...? (English is not my native language either)

Yes, I'm sorry, it turns out that when I select one face it shows up as white, and when there are two or more it shows up as orange I only realized this now.

I think @GordonBrinkmann is right. Looks like you have duplicate faces fighting over the same position in 3D space. When you pan or zoom the 3d viewport, that "interference" can change and flicker because they are fighting to be the one that the viewport shading shows. Try this: Go into edit mode and select all vertices with A. Then press M to bring up the Merge menu, and choose "By distance". If our theory is correct, the vertices of the duplicate faces will merge and there should only be one face remaining.

No, it didn't work. I want to clarify that these interferences apply to any figure. That is, I create a regular figure using shift+A, the face is selected and interference appears

Can you share your Blender project file? Instructions for sharing.
